# Create-react-app Command not found

Tags: reactjs, command, native

I'm currently learning React. Every time I write create-react-app my-app, I get -bash command not found.

I've tried every single solution out there and still not working. Can anybody please help me? It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the creat-react-app CLI?

`npm install -g create-react-app`

If bash can't find it, you may just need to install it globally (-g) before you try to use it.